# Using Tags vs. Cleaning Commits

Tags: git, rebase

I'm relatively new to `git`, and have been reading around a bit about proper workflows, but I'm struggling a little bit with the suggestions to `rebase` / `squash` commits into single cohesive commits prior to pushing to other repos (e.g. `github` in my case).

My main problem with this is that I'm a hobbyist programmer (1-2hrs a day if I'm lucky), which means it can often take me days or weeks to get to the point of a cohesive feature commit.  Furthermore, `github` is my back-up.  So my workflow typically consists of 1-5 small commits (many of which are of the "fixed stupid typo" variety) per evening, pushed once per evening to the `github` repo.  It seems that the goals of only publishing relatively clean commits and using `github` as a back-up are not compatible.

Instead of `rebase`ing my commits, I just add tags whenever I complete features or bug fixes.  This seems to me like a reasonable alternative as it:

- doesn't re-write history (which seems like a bad thing to do generally)
- allows you to look at only the significant commits by just filtering on the tags and diffing b/w tags
- is compatible with using another git repo (e.g. `github`) as a back-up in between "complete" commits

I've looked around a bit, but this never seems to be offered as an alternative to the "cleaned up" commit workflow.  Am I missing something?

Comment: There's no reason you can't commit to a backup branch, and clone/branch from it and squash to push to Github or elsewhere.

Comment: @isherwood, makes sense; would you consider the tag based approach bad practice?

Comment: Tags are mostly just friendly names for commits. Use them as you see fit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your statement that re-writing git history is generally a bad thing to do, especially if there are other people contributing to the same branch as you.

In order to maintain a git history on your master branch with commits that represent completed features, or sets of related bug fixes, I would recommend creating branches with a limited scope of what you wish to accomplish. For instance, your first 3 commits to master might look like

- Stub out client side models and views
- Update javascript libraries to latest versions
- Bug-fixes: fix event delegation and rendering discrepancies on Settings page

The first commit in the above list might be a series of commits from a branch you might have created named siteSetup that you rebased before you cherry-picked over into master.

This sample branch siteSetup might have the following commits

- Stub out client side models and views
- Oops >>
- Fix typo
- Fix yet another typo... Sigh

By using branches, you can feel free to "make a mess" out of your commits, as long as you rebase the commits to clean it up before committing your changes over to master.

Comment: Thanks (+1), but I guess my question is why is it not okay/acceptable to just merge my whole mess of commits into master and let people rely on the tags to identify the meaningful points and not worry about re-writing history.

Comment: The way that I use git tags is more or less outlined here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging. I use tags to indicate releases. The reason why I would not merge a mess of commits into master is because when a change log is put together for the release, the person cutting the release will have to sift through the commit messages at https://github.com/your-organization/your-repo/commits and this can potentially be very time consuming, especially if there are a large number of commits, or if the commit messages themselves are not very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go on a branch (limb) and suggest that the proper way to do these things is to avoid rebasing, branch eagerly, and most importantly, merge back with `--no-ff`.

This great **[2010 Vincent Driessen blog post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)** illustrates a workflow that lines up pretty much with what I was envisioning.  The main release branch remains fairly clean and can be inspected easily, but none of the history is re-written / lost.  The key piece is the merging with `--no-ff` which makes it very easy to see what commits are major commits vs. minor ones.  You don't even have to tag.

Then things like:

```
git checkout master
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate=full
git log --oneline --graph --all --simplify-by-decoration --decorate=full
```

Give you a birds eye view of what the major modifications to the master branch are.

I'm still fairly new to `git`, but I'm having a hard time envisioning under what circumstances `rebase`/`squash` should be preferable to this approach.